# Why polygon in R works with a full curve but not with a half curve?

Tags: r, plot, polygon

I'm wondering why `polygon()` works very well with a two-sided curve (***bottom picture***), but not working correctly with a half of that same curve (***top picture***)?

I appreciate a short explanation.

```
par(mfrow = c(2, 1))

gg = curve(dnorm(x), -4, 0) # Not working!
polygon(gg, col = 2)

gg = curve(dnorm(x), -4, 4) # Working!
polygon(gg, col = 2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## One `curve`

Since `polygon` connects the start and the end of your curve, it creates some weird shape. From `?polygon` we can see that

> "It is assumed that the polygon is to be closed by joining the last point to the first point."

The first and last points are given by the `from` and `to` values in `curve`. In your first case these are `-4` and `0`.

Just add `xlim` and `xaxs = "i"` to `curve()`

```
gg = curve(dnorm(x), -4, 4, xlim = c(-4,0), xaxs = "i") # Working!
polygon(gg, col = 2)
```

[image]

## Multiple `curve`s in one plot

When you want to put multiple curves in one plot, you might face the problem that you can't limit your axes as shown above. Thus, we have to dig deeper into the structure of a curve object (here `gg`).

Let's first create two curves.

```
gg = curve(dnorm(x), -4, 4) ; 
polygon(gg, col = 2) ; 
gg = curve(dnorm(x), -4, 0, xlim = c(-4,0), xaxs = "i", add = T) ;
```

Now we have a look at `gg`:

```
gg 
# $x
# [1] -4.00 -3.96 -3.92 -3.88 -3.84 -3.80 -3.76 -3.72 -3.68 -3.64 -3.60 -3.56 -3.52 -3.48 -3.44 -3.40 -3.36 -3.32 -3.28
# [20] -3.24 -3.20 -3.16 -3.12 -3.08 -3.04 -3.00 -2.96 -2.92 -2.88 -2.84 -2.80 -2.76 -2.72 -2.68 -2.64 -2.60 -2.56 -2.52
#  .....
# $y
# [1] 0.0001338302 0.0001569256 0.0001837125 0.0002147280 0.0002505784 0.0002919469 0.0003396012 0.0003944025 0.0004573148
# [10] 0.0005294147 0.0006119019 0.0007061107 0.0008135212 0.0009357722 0.0010746733 0.0012322192 0.0014106023 0.0016122275
#  .....
```

We see that `gg` is just a list of `$x` and `$y` coordinates. Thus, we can add one coordinate at `0, 0` to the second `gg` to simulate the end of the overlapping second curve. Afterwards both curves are plotted correctly.

```
gg$x <- c(gg$x, 0)
gg$y <- c(gg$y, 0)
polygon(gg, col = 4)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Loki shows you how to fill the curve as you want but does not explain why the half curve fills as it does, which is important if you are looking to use this function moving forward.

Because you are giving `polygon()` a single curved line, it closes both ends by drawing a straight line to connect them. Then it fills in the spaces between the curve and the new line.

The full distribution rises and drops to the same point on the y-axis creating a nice pretty filled curve. By stopping at the top of the curve, the line is drawn through the changes in direction leaving open spaces between the curve and the line on both sides, which `polygon()` fills them both.

Comment: Thanks, any quick fix to the `polygon()` (not using `plot()`) so that it doesn't draw that last straight line? I mean suppose you have the full two-sided curve, then you decide to shade the left tail of it using the half curve.